# AWS vpn assign static LOCAL IP address to the remote user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, static-ip-address

I have an AWS VPN set up.  I have just tested connecting and disconnecting to my VPN from my PC in my office. Everything works fine, but I noticed that each time I get a different IP address assigned to my remote PC.  For example:

- 12.0.0.32
- 12.0.0.147
- 12.0.0.92
  ...

I want to have the **same** local IP address assigned to the PC.  That way, I could set up a firewall rule to direct traffic from a particular domain to a specific port on my remote PC and do testing of some server code while in development mode, without resorting to something like ngrok.

**NOTE**: I believe my question is different from the many questions I have seen on SO where people want to have a static IP assigned to their VPN (public facing WAN address) or to their load balancer.  This is **not** what I want.  I just want the AWS side software to assign the *same* **local** IP address to my remote PC when I connect to the VPN so I can write the firewall rule to redirect traffic to my remote PC.  By **local** IP address I mean the IP address assigned to my remote PC as a node on the VPN private subnet.

I am the **only** user that connects to this VPN sub-net so there is no problem with locking out other users if the same local IP address is assigned to an incoming VPN client connection.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find any working solution yet?